# Is there a way to share a folder on Azure VM to public like a website?

Tags: networking, azure

Is there a way to let any user, accessing the website hosted on Azure server VM, access a folder on the same VM and run an exe placed there? The exe needs to run on the server as well as there are some installations on the server that are needed by the exe to run.
I know that I can give access and share folder to the users of the network but the target audience are the users regardless of whichever network and location they access the site and folder from.

Totally new to all this so please share any resources that might be helpful for me to learn as well.

Comment: What do you actually want them to do, you say run an exe. but are they launching an application they need to interact with?

Comment: Yes, the exe needs to run on the server and the user needs to access that folder after performing certain actions on the website. Ideally, the link for that folder should be displayed to the frontend from where the user can click and open that. Its like sharing a folder via going to properties but should be shared to everyone, not just people of the network. 

I understand this is not the best practices and this design can be made better but due to certain technical reasons we have to go with this approach for now. Any suggestions on how I can get this done?